# Does conjugation by half invertible matrices preserve spectrum?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Conjugation by an invertible matrix preserves the spectrum, but does conjugation by a left/right invertible matrix also preserve spectrum? My motivating situation was considering non-unitary isometries/coisometries over an (infinite dimensional) Hilbert space. I get the feeling the answer is no, but I'm not familiar enough with Hilbert spaces to have a pet example to think about.

Comment: Are you thinking finite matrices here?  Are your left/right invertible matrices square, or can they be rectangular?

Comment: I was thinking of infinite matrices- consequently I'm not sure if square/rectangular makes sense in this context?